# how can i take the comma separated ip addresses in django form?

Tags: python, html, django

i have to create a form which can take mutiple IP addresses **(comma separated)** from user, run the desired command (input from user) and display it on the web page.

i could not figure out how can i do it.

Currently the code is able to take single IP address, run command and display the result on web page, successfully.!

forms .py

```
from django import forms

class CmdForm(forms.Form):
        ip_address = forms.CharField(label='Enter IP address:')
        command = forms.CharField(label='Command to execute:')
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from first_app.forms import CmdForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
import netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
import datetime, time, sys
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_me': ""}
    return render(request,'first_app/index.html',context=my_dict)

def form_name_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CmdForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from netmiko import ConnectHandler
            ipInsert = request.POST.get('ip_address', '')
            devices = {
            'device_type':'cisco_ios',
            'ip':ipInsert,
            'username':'mee',
            'password':'12345',
            'secret':'12345',
            }
            cmd = request.POST.get('command', '')
            try:
                netconnect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
            except (AuthenticationException):
                re = 'Authentication failed.! please try again {}'.format(ipInsert)
                print(re)
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                pass
            except (SSHException):
                re = 'SSH issue. Are you sure SSH is enabled? {}'.format(ipInsert)
                print(re)
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                pass
            except (NetMikoTimeoutException):
                re = 'TimeOut to device {}'.format(ipInsert)
                print(re)
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                pass
            except (EOFError):
                print ("End of file while attempting device " + ipInsert)
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                pass
            except Exception as unknown_error:
                print ('Some other error: ' + str(unknown_error))
                return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'reprinting':re})
                pass

            getIP = netconnect.send_command(ipInsert)
            output = netconnect.send_command(cmd)
            now = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S")
            file = sys.stdout
            file = open("C:/Users/karti/OneDrive/Desktop/frontend/ "+now +".txt", mode='w+')
            file.write("IP address is\n"+ ipInsert)
            file.write("\n\nCommand Executed: \n"+ cmd)
            file.write("\n\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
            file.write("\n\nOutput of Executed Command: \n\n\n"+output)
            file.close

            return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form, 'output':output, 'getIP':getIP, 'date_time':now})
        else:
            form = CmdForm()
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request,'first_app/forms.html', {})
```

forms.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FORMS</title>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1> IP address form </h1>

<br><br>
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Run command!" />
<br>

{% if request.POST %}
<pre>{{ reprinting }}</pre>
{% endif %}

<br>

<p>Current date and time is : {{ date_time }} </p>
{% if request.POST %}
<p>Command output:</p>
<pre>{{ output }}</pre>
{% endif %}



  </body>
</html>
```

for single ip:- The workflow is forms.py takes in the **Single IP** address and **command* from user then that IP& command is passed onto views.py for processing [refer to code in views.py]  and forms.html is used for User Interface.

Requirement is:- now the user must be able to give multiple IP addresses (separating them using commas) and runs the command on the devices of that IP.

Hope u get what i m trying to tell.!
thnx for the help

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: unclear question.

Comment: `ip_addresses = ips_input.split(sep=",")` to get a list from one string, then loop over it and exacute the command just like you would do with a single ip

Comment: @h4z3 thx for ur reply but it didnt worked.!

Comment: So write more. You haven't posted any relevant code, just fields. Of course you need to get that input from fields. Of course the execution might depend on what is the "command". Tell us more. I only said how to separate the string by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal `forms.CharField()`, then split the result string with `ip_addresses.split(',')`, the split method will return the list of ip addresses.

Comment: tried your code but getting the error ------------>  AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: mhh, you are calling the method on form.ip_addresses, that's wrong, the property is not a string. You should first understand how Django forms work: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_form_processing.htm

Comment: i do have a basic knowledge of django forms and for a while i was reasearching about what could be the possible solutions of the problem. and found that split wont work with django form input. Again describing the problem this time in detail.-----------> i have to take comma separated values (IP addresses to be specific) from user as input --> store it in the form of list and then pass the list to **Views.py** and for each value (IP) the command so entered would produce the result.                                               thanx for the help  :-)